# Python modify tuples inside a list

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
myList=[(u"hell world", 10),(u"hello mom", 20), (u"hello dad","5")]
```

I need to modify each tuple in order to get back a list like this:

```
mySecondList= [(u"hell",u"world","10"),(u"hello",u"mom","20"), (u"hello",u"dad","5")]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so you'll need to return a list with new tuples.

Comment: Post your attempts..

Comment: Try using the string `.split` method. If you get stuck, post your code and explain exactly what it's doing wrong.

Comment: How can I do it by coding?

Answer (score 3):

You may achieve the desired behavior using *list comprehension* expression as:

```
[tuple(item[0].split() + [str(item[1])])  for item in myList]
```

which will return:

```
[(u'hell', u'world', '10'), (u'hello', u'mom', '20'), (u'hello', u'dad', '5')]
```

---

*Note*: [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) are immutable in nature. You can not modify the existing tuple object. Here I am returning new list with newly created tuple objects

Comment: @AvinashRaj He's using Python 2 ;-) EDIT: Ah never mind, the third component is a regular bytestring.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment tuples are immutable, but you can use something like the following code:

```
def modify(lst):
    ret = []
    for tpl in lst:
        ret.append(tuple([tpl[0].split(' '), tpl[1]]))
    return ret
```

Or you can use a generator and pass it to the `tuple` constructor:

```
new_list = tuple(item[0].split(' ') + [item[1]]) for item in myData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are an immutable type, so you won't be able to change the contents once they are created.  Perhaps you should try lists, which are mutable.